# OneTrust not working. Error message in console

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to implement OneTrust for cookie consent into a site I made months ago. When I add the scripts code everything goes ok in localhost: it shows the message, the popup for cookie customization... but when I put it in production nothing appears but a message in console which says:

> Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://salesiq.zoho.com https://js.zohocdn.com  https://webforms.pipedrive.com https://leadbooster-chat.pipedrive.com/ https://cdn.eu-central-1.pipedriveassets.com https://sc.lfeeder.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://code.jquery.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com  https://stats.wp.com https://www.gstatic.com http://www.googletagmanager.com https://s0.wp.com https://s1.wp.com https://s2.wp.com https://ajax.googleapis.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.youtube.com  https://s.ytimg.com https://platform.linkedin.com https://platform.twitter.com  https://apis.google.com https://connect.facebook.net https://player.vimeo.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

And the code I added to my header is:

```
<!-- El aviso de consentimiento de cookies de OneTrust comienza para www.---.com. -->
<script src="https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="***-***-***-***-***" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function OptanonWrapper() { }
</script>
<!-- El aviso de consentimiento de cookies de OneTrust finaliza para www.---.com. -->
```

It would be great if someone could tell me where is the error. If it is in the code itself or if it comes from the libraries I'm using (Analytics, jQuery, Bootstrap...).

Thank you!

Comment: The error message tells exactly what is going wrong: "_it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self_". Either edit or remove the [directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src), or store the script into your own server.

Comment: can you tell me where you found docs describing where to put the script? their docs seem to hide everything pertinent to initial setup

Answer (score 0):

Add script-src directive with having this domain as allowed list.
Content-Security-Policy: script-src https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/;

It is not new directive but already should be present as you have allowed list for many domains.

Answer (score 0):

it's recommended to add -test at the end of your data domain script for staging environnements.

You need to add "https://cdn.mycompany.com/script.js" to the "script-src" directive of the policy. There are tools that can automatically generate policies such as CSP Generator.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was Service Worker caching some One Trust requests. One Trust is using wired `content-type=text/x-javascript` for one of the json requests.

You can check if your application is using some `window.fetch` polyfill that cannot handle requests to OneTrust.

```
Error in fetch URL : https://cdn.cookielaw.org/consent/XXX/YYY/en.json Exception : TypeError: r is undefined
```

from `https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/6.5.0/otBannerSdk.js`